# How to get nested object's value in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have such mongoose schema:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    dateCreated: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    userData: {
        tasks: [
            {
                description: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true,
                },
                dateCreated: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true,
                },
                completed: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    required: false,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
});
```

And when I try to get the `tasks` array like this:

```
async findSingleTodo(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> {
        UserModel.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
            .select('userData.tasks')
            .then((todos) => this.sendWithStatus(res, 200, todos))
            .catch((err) => this.sendWithStatus(res, 500, err.message));
    }
```

I get such result

```
{
"userData": {
    "tasks": [
        {
            "description": "qwrqwr",
            "dateCreated": "123",
            "_id": "640dd79c827ed1719519a3a0"
        },
    ]
},
"_id": "640dcd1590f7f0f1be5d82e3"
```

}

But I would like to get only tasks array, how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

To get only the tasks array without the parent userData object, you can use the lean() to convert it to JSON and specify the tasks field in the select() method:

```
async findSingleTodo(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> {
    UserModel.findOne({ _id: req.params.id })
        .select('userData.tasks -_id') // exclude _id field from the tasks array
        .lean() // convert the result to a plain JavaScript object
        .then((todos) => this.sendWithStatus(res, 200, todos.userData.tasks))
        .catch((err) => this.sendWithStatus(res, 500, err.message));
}
```

More about the function you can find it here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html

Comment: the problem not because I've got id value, the problem that I've got object in promise - todos and then I need to get it like this todos.userData.tasks
But how I can get tasks array in promise without userData ?